# How to get total number of albums of all my Facebook friends?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, fql.multiquery

I want to retrieve all facebook friends total number of albums in one go

Anyone know how to query album table

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

`SELECT location, link FROM album WHERE owner IN (SELECT uid2 from friend where uid1 = me())`

or for testing: go to 
`https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>&query=SELECT%20location,%20link%20FROM%20album%20WHERE%20owner%20IN%20%28SELECT%20uid2%20from%20friend%20where%20uid1%20=%20me%28%29%29`